# Upload an image to amazon S3 using VichUploaderBundle

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, amazon-s3, vichuploaderbundle

I am using VichUploaderBundle to upload images to AmazonS3 in symfony-2.

I have followed this documentation https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md and created my entity class.

So I have a setter method in the entity

```
/**
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(File $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->updated = new \DateTime();
}
```

The client (This is a web application) will be sending the image in base_64 format.
So I dont understand how will i get a FILE object out of that string? (Since the parameter of setter method is FILE)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UploadedBase64EncodedFile` class from the [hshn/base64-encoded-file](https://github.com/hshn/base64-encoded-file) library:

```php
use Hshn\Base64EncodedFile\HttpFoundation\File\Base64EncodedFile;
use Hshn\Base64EncodedFile\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedBase64EncodedFile;

$uploadedFile = new UploadedBase64EncodedFile(
    new Base64EncodedFile($base64String)
);
$uploadableEntity->setFile($uploadedFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first you need to save the image to a temporary file - here is a solution for that: [How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

Then you need to create an instance of an UploadedFile using that file, kind of like this example: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/203

And then send this UploadedFile to your setFile() method.